# Loading the Market Price for ETH-USD using Coinbase-Pro-Trading-Toolkit

Tags: coinbase-api

I am using the Coinbase-Pro-Trading-Toolkit (Coinbase Pro API)
There are several ways to get the market price using the toolkit. I am not trying to run a live feed, I simply want to use the API, so I'm looking at a couple different methods:

```
publicClient.getProductTicker(product)
coinbasePro.loadMidMarketPrice(product)
```

Both of these work great when I pass in a product of "BTC-USD". But when I try passing in "ETH-USD" it fails. Are these methods designed to work with certain products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I feel silly with this one. The issue was that I was using the sandbox api and not all products appear in the Sandbox API. Only API calls to Coinbase Pro’s production site will produce a full result set.

Good news is that all products have same attributes and therefore testing in the Sandbox is possible.